# (Django/HTML) How to create Add to favorite Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to create a Add to Favorite function, so far I manage to display an button with icon that based on if the field `is_favorite` but I can't update my database.

My Question is : How can I change the favorite state and update it to my database without refreshing the page

**EDIT** : 
**[SOLVED]** Thanks to @Nazkter and a project from Bucky Robert. I edited the working code below

Here's my code :

model.py

```
class ProjectProfile(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

views.py

```
def index_view(request):
    context = {
        "table_list": ProjectProfile.objects.all(),
        "title": "Table_List"
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def favorite_project(request, projectprofile_id):
    projectprofile = get_object_or_404(ProjectProfile, pk=projectprofile_id)
    try:
        if projectprofile.is_favorite:
            projectprofile.is_favorite = False
        else:
            projectprofile.is_favorite = True
        projectprofile.save()
    except (KeyError, ProjectProfile.DoesNotExist):
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index_view, name='index_view'),
    url(r'^(?P<projectprofile_id>[0-9]+)/favorite_album/$', favorite_project, name='favorite_project'),
]
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Favorite function</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Favorite Function</h1>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Favorite</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for data in table_list %}{% csrf_token %}
            <tr >

                <td>{{data.project_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.artist}}</td>
                <!-- Favorite Album -->
                <td><a href="{% url 'favorite_project' data.id %}"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-favorite" role="button"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-star {% if data.is_favorite %}active{% endif %}" action=""></span></a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

javascript

```
var ProjectListPage = {
    init: function() {
        this.$container = $('.project-container');
        this.render();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    render: function() {

    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $('.btn-favorite', this.$container).on('click', function(e) {
            console.log('Hola');
            e.preventDefault();

            var self = $(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('.glyphicon-star', self).toggleClass('active');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ProjectListPage.init();
});
```

Comment: Do you have a python API that exposes your database in a way that allows ajax to communicate with it? If so, you can bind an click event to the button, and write jquery to post a JSON object to your python API end point which then writes to the DB.

Comment: Hello @JacobIRR Thank you for your input, your referring to REST API right? I'll try to implement it to my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Nazkter is already way ahead of me. That answer is the implementation of what I was suggesting.

Comment: @JacobIRR Nevertheless you input is still much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I've tried it and it gives me an error ( didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make an ajax call to a kind of service in your Django server.

First, you need to make an url to get the ajax petition (urls.py):

```
url(r'^ajax_is_favorite/$', views.ajax_is_favorite, name='ajax_is_favorite'),
```

Next, you need to add a functión to resolve the petition (views.py):

```
def ajax_is_favorite(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() or not request.method=='POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
    else:
        #Here you have to get the data and update the object
        return HttpResponse({"success":True})
```

Finally, you need to make an ajax function in your template to make a call to the service:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "{% url 'ajax_is_favorite'%}",
    data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
        'ProjectProfileID': 'here you get the id',
        'isFavorite':true //or false
    },
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        if(json.success === true){
            // do somthing
        }else{
            // do somthing
        }
    }
});
```

Do not forget to add the {% csrf_token %} tag in your template, it is necessary for the request.

Comment: Hi @Nazkter, Thanks for your input, this is what i tried yesterday based on The New Boston sample project but it a bit confusing. thank you for simplify this for me. I'll implement this immediately, if anything I'll reply again soon

Comment: @M.Izzat Please make an ask at the time, you erased the main question and put the &quot;optional&quot; as the new question. Please revert your changes, if my answer works, you can set it as the correct answer and finally open other question for a different problem.

Comment: my apologies I ill change back the question, I'm aware that stackoverflow has a limit on how many question you can ask, since its in the same topic I thought I change it, Thank you for your help and sorry for the incovenient

Comment: @M.Izzat I'm glad it helps you, if my answer is what you needed then you can mark it as the correct answer.